# class name suggestions for a class full of containers

Tags: c++, variables, naming-conventions, variable-names

I have a class as follows

```
class Package
{
    list<string> targetList;
    list<string> excludedList;
    map<string, string> mapping;
};
```

I will be using data structures of type, *Package*, **contained** within several other classes which might require to  compute further information based on this ***input*** *Package* P

For example, a handler which has an instance P of *Package*, might need to do *targetList* = *targetList* - {*targetList* ^ *excludedList*} and after subtracting the intersection it might map every *targetList* string to a new string w.r.t *mapping*.

With names like Package, Input, InputCollection, Collection someone else reading my code won't be able to understand what it might contain. I'm looking for nice name suggestions, as getting the rightvariable name seems self-documenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this highly depends on your problem domain and cannot be answered without the context.

You should ask yourself whether it is a general purpose library providing an algorithm or if it is solving a specific problem of your domain?

Be as specific to your domain or algorithm as possible.

Maybe this is helping you: http://www.itiseezee.com/?p=83

Just to take out one rule of thumb:

> Readers should not need to mentally translate your names into other
>   names they already know/are familiar with. This problem generally
>   arises from a choice to use NEITHER problem-domain terms nor
>   solution-domain terms (see more, below, on problem-domain and
>   solution-domain).